# get the first word as result of ls -l

Tags: linux, bash, ls

I need to use `ls -l` and I would like to have as result just the first word of the file name for instance for a result like this

```
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             9 Sep 21 23:11 best file 1.txt
```

I would like to have only

```
best
```

as result because I need to put this value into a variable. It is ok as well if there is another way instead of using `ls -l`.

...sorry to bother you again...if the file is under a sub-directory, how can I hide the folder from the result? Thanks

Comment: **Don't parse the output of ls**

Comment: @avinash: some justification might be useful ;)

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth see the link in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have only one row to output, this will work fine:

```
var=`ls -l | awk '{ print $9 }'`
echo ${var}
```

Or you need to use `grep` to filter your output for the correct file.

Comment: guys, I made a mix of your all solutions to finally solve the problem...many thanks to all of you for your effort and kind support!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `ls -l` (L).

Instead, use `ls -1` (number one), that just outputs the names of the files, and then filter out the first column with `cut`:

```
ls -1 | cut -d' ' -f1
    ^
    number one, not letter L
```

To store the value into a variable, do:

```
var=$(ls -1 | cut -d' ' -f1)
```

Note it is not a good thing to parse `ls`: the number of columns may vary, etc. You can read more about the topic in [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

#### Update

Note there is no even need to use `-1` (one), `ls` alone suffices:

```
ls | cut -d' ' -f1
```

As [BroSlow comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26083837/get-the-first-word-as-result-of-ls-l/26083867#comment40953245_26083867) below, *"because they are EOL (end of line) separated across a pipe"*.

Comment: Many thanks all of you guys, all solutions are perfectly working, and thanks for the hints

Comment: Don't think the `-1` actually does anything here, since they're eol separated across a pipe anyway.

Comment: @BroSlow pretty true. Updated, many thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
set -- $(ls -l)
echo ${11}    # Assumes the file is the FIRST one listed.
```

Should do the trick. But I'm not sure if that's really what you want. For one thing, `ls -l` also prints an extra header line. Why do you say that you *need to use ls -l*? If you could state the actual problem, maybe we can find a much better solution together...

Answer (score 0):

`awk` can pick the first word for you;

```
ls | awk '{print $1}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ls -al|awk 'NR==4{ print $9 }'
```

Row number 4 will have first line of files. $9 indicates column 9 which will have desired word.

Comment: What is the use of `NR==4` here?

Comment: You wanted only name of first file. First 3 lines contain . or .. etc. Hence Row Number (NR) 4 has details of first file. Column number 9 has its name.

Comment: If parsing ls alone is bad, parsing ls taking into consideration the ., .., etc is even more dangerous. I recommend a read to [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: I agree with you but the OP wanted ls -l. I think the OP should take your advice and use ls -1 (one) as mentioned earlier by you.